# Android setFocusable on AutoCompleteText?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I was just wondering if `setFocusable` works with AutoComplete text view.

I looked for examples and implemented it but setFocusable (in my observation) works only with EditText. Does setFocusable works with AutoComplete text view?

If not, are there any ways to implement such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

According to documentation, it does. I also can make it not focusable simply calling `setFocusable( )`.

Try to set also `setFocusableInTouchMode( )`, maybe you have default focus set on it;